# Node js request - Get source code from url and stock it in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, request

I'm using request and Node JS to get source code from a webpage and stock it in a variable in order to work on it after.

```
var request = require('request');
var htmldata="";
request('https://www.nba.com', function (error, response, body) {
  htmldata=body;
});
console.log(htmldata);
```

I want the variable *htmldata* to get the value of the parameter of the function *body* which contains the source code but it returns me a blank string.

I thank you in advance if you resolve my problem

Comment: You're making an async request.  You need to have your `console.log` within the callback from request.

Comment: oh ok thank you for your answers

Answer (score -2):

Place console.log inside the function.

```
var request = require('request');
var htmldata="";
request('https://www.nba.com', function (error, response, body) {
  htmldata=body;
  console.log(htmldata);
});
```

Put the console.log inside the callback function because javascript is async and the request method takes time, so by the time console.log runs, the request method has not completed its call yet. – thanks @ Mohammad Ganji

Comment: Ok but how can I work with my variable after this instruction ?

Comment: you better complete your answer, add a little more description,
like he should put the console.log inside the callback function because javascript is async and the request method takes time, so by the time console.log runs, the request method has not completed its call yet.

Comment: you can work with it inside the callback function, or you can make your request function to return a promise and when the promise is fulfilled, you can then use your variable

Comment: outside of the function you can test for htmldata for content.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will work inside the callback function